# find duplicate files with different filenames in different folders, sync their filenames

Tags: python, shell, applescript

I have some important files in FOLDER A, then I back them up in FOLDER B on a different drive.

```
FOLDER A:   Filename01. Filename02. Filename03. ...

FOLDER B:   Filename01. Filename02. Filename03. ...
```

Then I rename Filename02 in FOLDER B to Filename02new.

```
FOLDER A:   Filename01. Filename02. Filename03. ...

FOLDER B:   Filename01. Filename02new. Filename03. ...
```

Now I want to sync these two folders. Change Filename02 in FOLDER A to Filename02new.
If there are many many identical files in these two folders having different filenames, is there a quick way, automatic way, or any software can do this job - find duplicates with different filenames in different folders, then sync their filenames?

Comment: Were the files renamed with just a suffix or prefix?  How are you going to determine that the files are identical?

Comment: DirSync Pro is great for mirrors, sync of directories.  Now if you have files that are identical, but with different filenames, I do not know of any soft that does that.  You could build a list of checkums for each file, in each directory.  Then compare these checksum values to find identical files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set folderA to choose folder -- alias
set folderB to choose folder -- alias

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with i from 1 to count (items of folderA)
        set aItem to item i of folderA
        set aSize to size of aItem
        set posix_Path_1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of (aItem as text))
        repeat with j from 1 to count (items of folderB)
            set bItem to item j of folderB
            set bSize to size of bItem
            
            if aSize = bSize then -- if size is  same, than items can be duplicates
                set posix_Path_2 to quoted form of (POSIX path of (bItem as text))
                -- compare items further
                set shell_Command_String to "cmp -s" & posix_Path_1 & space & posix_Path_2
                set exitStatus to 0 -- setting initial status of shell operation
                try
                    set exitStatus to do shell script shell_Command_String
                    return exitStatus
                end try
                if exitStatus = 0 then -- if exitStatus remains= 0, that indicates "files is same"
                    set name of aItem to name of bItem
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
            
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Amazing work from @Robert Kniazidis. Some small fixes make his code works on my machine. I cannot edit his code directly. So post these fixes here. I accept his answer. but people should note these fixes.

Comment: FIX A: use new variables numberA and numberB to define the number of files in folders. `set numberA to count files of entire contents of folderA` `set numberB to count files of entire contents of folderB` `repeat with i from 1 to numberA` `repeat with j from 1 to numberB`

Comment: FIX B: change `"cmp -s"` to `"cmp "`......FIX C: remove the line `return exitStatus`......FIX D: change `if exitStatus = 0 then` to `if exitStatus ≠ 0 then`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot edit Robert's code, so I post edited code here:

```
set folderA to choose folder 
set folderB to choose folder 

tell application "Finder"
    set numberA to count files of entire contents of folderA
    set numberB to count files of entire contents of folderB
    
    repeat with i from 1 to numberA
        set aItem to item i of folderA
        set aSize to size of aItem
        set posix_Path_1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of (aItem as text))
        repeat with j from 1 to numberB
            set bItem to item j of folderB
            set bSize to size of bItem
            
            if aSize = bSize then
                set posix_Path_2 to quoted form of (POSIX path of (bItem as text))
                set shell_Command_String to "cmp " & posix_Path_1 & space & posix_Path_2
                set exitStatus to 0
                try
                    set exitStatus to do shell script shell_Command_String
                end try
                if exitStatus ≠ 0 then
                    set name of aItem to name of bItem
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
            
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "I cannot edit Robert's code, so I post edited code here:" -- JSYK  You can do a _suggested edit_ and wait for it to be approved, either by the author of the post, or those that have the reputation to approve it in the review cue.